# How to fix Axios GET request not working with Electron.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, electron, passport.js

I'm trying to build a Oauth login for my electron app but when I try to make a request GET with Axios to check if a user is logged in already it refuses to work. It seemingly works fine though when I test the request on my react project.

[Picture of error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTBtH.png)

Here is the main.js file:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
require('isomorphic-fetch');

const { createAuthWindow } = require('./main/auth-process');
const createAppWindow = require('./main/app-process');
const { getUserDetails } = require('../src/utils/api')


async function showWindow() {
  console.log('showWindow Started!');

  await getUserDetails()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('Success!');
        return createAppWindow();
      }
      else {
        createAuthWindow();
        throw new Error('Failed to authenticate user.');
      }
    })
}

app.on('ready', showWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
})
```

Here is the api request:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function getUserDetails() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/', { withCredentials: true });
}

module.exports = { getUserDetails }
```

Index.js on server

```
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const passport = require('passport');
const passportSetup = require('./config/passport')
const session = require('express-session');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth-routes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

mongoose.connect(keys.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: [keys.COOKIE_KEY],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100
  })
)

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true
  })
)

app.use('/auth', authRoutes);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.send({ user: req.user });
  }
  else {
    res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Unauthorized' })
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}!`));
```

Auth Routes file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const homeURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

router.get('/login/success', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'User has successfully authenticated.',
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies
    })
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
    });
  }
})

router.get('/login/failed', (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'User failed to authenticate.'
  })
})

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(homeURL);
})

router.get('/osu', passport.authenticate('osu'));

router.get(
  '/osu/redirect',
  passport.authenticate('osu', {
    successRedirect: homeURL,
    failureRedirect: '/auth/login/failed'
  })
)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why `withCredentials`? Are you using cookie based authentication?

Comment: Yes I'm using cookie based auth on my server

Comment: I only ask as typically, OAuth logins are token based. Seems odd to mix them

Comment: Sorry what I meant is I'm using cookies to store my mongo connect and my Oauth is token based.

Comment: A 401 means you haven't provided the correct credentials in your request. With OAuth, this would typically be an `Authorization` header with bearer token

Comment: The problem is that when I pass the same exact same function on a button on a reactjs with my electron app the request works just fine. So I'm sure why it wouldn't work in main.js

Comment: Nope I can update my question with the code from my react app

Comment: I think your server code would be more apt. How have you configured authentication?

Comment: I'm using passport to handle authentication and authorization on my backend

Comment: Ah I see my bad I posted my indexjs in the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can not use axios with session in main or preload, need to call axios funcion in index.js file loaded in browserwindow.